# Identity witness in set theory

Tags: set-theory, foundations

In set theory is there a standard witness that two sets are "the same?"

Something like

$$ A \sim B = \{ \emptyset \mid A = B \} \cup \{ \{ \emptyset \} \mid A \ne B \}$$

Feels very ad-hoc

Something like the set of identity isomorphisms feels perverse

$$ A \sim B = \{ f \in A \cong B \mid \forall x \in A. f x = x \} $$

Comment: In classical logic, within which set theory is usually conducted, statements don't necessarily have witnesses at all. In particular, the "propositions-as-types" paradigm isn't generally used. So I think the thing you're looking for doesn't exist.

Comment: as Noah says, there's not really any kind of "standard witness". but you could use [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference); note that $A=B$ iff $A\vartriangle B=\varnothing$

Comment: @NoahSchweber I kind of expected things wouldn't be simple. I'm messing about with some meta stuff and I was hoping it would be possible to construct a witness such that $\vdash \forall x. \exists y. y \in x \sim x$ and $\vdash \forall x y z. z \in x \sim y \rightarrow x =y $. But I shouldn't have expected anything standard.

Comment: @MolossusSpondee Given how primitive equality is taken to be in classical logic, I would just take $$x\sim y=\{(x,y): x=y\}.$$ Trivially $x\sim y$ is empty if $x\not=y$ and has a unique element if $x=y$. I suspect this won't satisfy you, but at this point you'll need to specify some further desiderata: what are you actually *trying to do?* (Higher-complexity formulas are more amenable to this sort of analysis, via *Skolem functions* and related ideas, but in classical logic there's not much to say re: atomic formulas, especially equality.)

Comment: @NoahSchweber I think that might work. I need to think some things through

Answer (score 3):

The notion of witness is applied to existential sentences: a *witness* for $\exists x \phi(x)$ is a specific $c$ such that $\phi(c)$ holds (in the context of some model, or as a step in a proof).

Now, in ZF, $A=B$ is equivalent (by the Axiom of Extensionality) to a universal sentence, namely $\forall x (x\in A \iff x\in B).$  Since the quantifier here is $\forall$ rather than $\exists,$ the idea of a witness doesn't seem useful.

Contrast this with the negation $A\ne B.$  This is equivalent to the existential sentence $\exists x ((x\in A \land x\notin B) \lor (x\in B \land x \notin A)).$  So it makes sense to ask for a witness to $A\ne B;$ this would be some set $c$ such that $(c\in A \land c\notin B) \lor (c\in B \land c \notin A).$

If you rig up some artificial way to view $A=B$ as an existential sentence (which is essentially what OP would be doing with the examples called "ad-hoc" or "perverse" in the question, if you wrote them out), it's not going to reveal anything interesting.

Comment: An [apartness witness](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/apartness+relation) might be more reasonable. I would need to think about that. I guess you would want some member of A that does not occur in B

Comment: @MolossusSpondee Yes, something like that could work, depending on what you want to do with this witness.